# Fail to list files on adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

i'm trying to access my database file from adb shell, but sqlite3 cant open it, i think this is because i dont have root, searching on the web i found that to get root acess you need to:

```
adb root ->adbd is restarted as root(dont really know what is this)
adb connect <device>
adb -s <device> shell
```

this commands work fine here, but i still cant get root access and still cant acess my database file

The error i'm getting is:

```
Error: unable to open database "ClientsInfoDB.db": unable to open database      file 1
```

on my app code to create the database i use:

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, "ClientsInfoDB", null, 2);
```

can anyone help me here?
thanks for attention

EDITED --- 
Important informations that was missing(sorry for that :s): i'm using Blluestacks to run my app

To access the app directory i did(on the shell):

```
cd data/data/<my_package_name>/databases
ls --> wont work
sqlite3 ClientsInfoDB
.databases --> message error that i posted above
```

Comment: post more of the error logs and the `DatabaseHelper` class.  As for the root stuff,  use an emulator

Comment: i'm using bluestacks to run the app

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard version of Android (i.e. *not* AOSP) you won't be able to get root by default. The steps for rooting the phone vary based on manufacturer and version and sometimes you can find instructions online. That said, it's not something that is officially supported and may damage your phone.

That said, without doing that, you can't access your application's database without root because the data directory for your application is restricted to your application only. If you need to access it, try having your application store the database somewhere like the `/sdcard` or equivalent directory which is generally accessible. The downside to this is that *any* application can access it, so be careful what you put there in production.

Comment: I understand, but if i need root and i enabled root why  i cant access the database? i'm not comfortable with putting my database outside my app directory

Comment: Honestly I would just do an adb pull to pull the db file off the device and view it with an app on your desktop.